# Insert clause of HQL not updating the database

Tags: java, hibernate, hql

Here is the servlet which performs the insert operation:

InsertClause.java

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    try (PrintWriter out = response.getWriter()) {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        out.println("<!DOCTYPE html>");
        out.println("<html>");
        out.println("<head>");
        out.println("<title>Servlet HibInsert</title>");            
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");

        Configuration cfg= new Configuration();
        cfg= cfg.configure("hibernate.cfg.xml");
        SessionFactory sf= cfg.buildSessionFactory();
        Session ses=sf.openSession();
        Transaction tx= ses.beginTransaction();
        out.println("execution...");    

        Query q= ses.createQuery("insert into Student(id,age) select ns.id,ns.age from NewStudent ns where ns.id=109");

        int res= q.executeUpdate();
        out.println("transfer successfull !!<br/>");
        out.println("number of records transferred: "+res);

        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");
    }
}
```

Other files used in the application are:

1.Student.java (POJO)

2.NewStudent.java (POJO)

3.student.hbm.xml

4.newstudent.hbm.xml

5.hibernate.cfg.xml

Two tables used in the database: newstudent and mystudent

The output on the browser am getting:

transfer successfull !!

number of records transferred: 1

But in the database when i open mystudent table the record is not inserted! So what could have gone wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to commit your transaction after `executeUpdate()` method.

```
Transaction tx= ses.beginTransaction();
out.println("execution...");    

Query q= ses.createQuery("insert into Student(id,age) select ns.id,ns.age 
                             from NewStudent ns where ns.id=109");

int res= q.executeUpdate();
tx.commit(); // Add this line.
```

Comment: thanks!. Actually i tried with tx.commit() before 'executeupdate'. now i got it right.